# NOT NULL constraint failed: articles_comment.article_id

Tags: django, database

I am following a tutorial where i build a newspaper app. So far so good but know I'm trying too add a comments section. If I add the comment true the admin in django i can see the comment and delete and update the comment on my site. But when i want too add a comment on the site I get the following error: NOT NULL constraint failed: articles_comment.article_id. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

class Article(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     body = models.TextField()
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.title

     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

 class Comment(models.Model):
     article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments',)
     comment = models.TextField()
     author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)


     def __str__(self):
          return self.comment

     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('comment_detail',)
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Article, Comment

class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'

class ArticleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'

class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ('title', 'body')
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user

 class ArticleDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user

class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_new.html'
    fields = ('title', 'body')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class CommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    template_name = 'comment_edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user

class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    fields = ('comment',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
         obj = self.get_object()
         return obj.author == self.request.user
```

Comment: How do you keep trackin your `CommentCreateView` what `Article` you are commenting about?

Comment: That is a little bit the problem, i do not know how to track it. I think thats why its failing. I need to add the comment to the specific id off the article but i do not know how

Comment: yes, since your `ForeignKey` to `Article` has no `null=True`, it needs to be "linked" to an `Article`.

Comment: Ok! I understand, but how do I do that, i tried to do it with the id off the article with this code:     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_detail', args=[str(article.id)])   But thats not oke